# How to set session in magento observer and get it in controller?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an Api call in observer function.

From there, I got a order details.I need to sent that order id  into the corresponding controller.
How I get this order id value into my controller?

Can i set it as a session value from observer to controller?

Comment: Pass that order id parameter to your controller function

Comment: How can I pass the order id to controller?

Comment: Can you specify how you call controller function from Observer?

Comment: <controller_action_postdispatch_batch_controller_batch>
                <observers>
                    <batchcode>
                         <class>Bridge_Batchcode_Model_Observer</class>
                         <method>saveInvoiceOrders</method>
                     </batchcode>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_batch_controller_batch>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you already have some knowledge of setting up the observer and controller, but let me know if that is not the case, and I will expand my answer.

**In the observer (app/code/local/Package/Vendor/Model/Observer.php):**

```
if($session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')) {
    $session->setData("some_variable_name");
}
```

**In the controller (path will vary):**

```
if($session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')) {
    $passed_value = $session->getData("some_variable_name");
}
// do something with $passed_value
```

Comment: I have used this code but it's not getting in my controller. session successfully set in observer file but visible in controller.

Comment: My controller is in front end and model in admin side.

Comment: @MarySebastian, you can try using `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')`, which is not specific to the customer.  There is more information about session types [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17539957/5517065)